# Understanding the diffusion operator in Grover's algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm

I understand how Grover's algorithm works and its geometrical interpretation. However, I am struggling to understand the implementation of the diffusion operator. Whilst I know what the diffusion operator does, i.e. the reflection about the quantum state, I cannot see why we need to apply Hadamard gates before and after the actual reflection.

For example, if we want to realize the reflection (diffusion) about the state $|++\rangle$, we implement the operator in terms of $H^{\otimes 2} (2|00\rangle \langle00| - I) H^{\otimes 2}$. Why do we have to go from $|+\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ to $|+\rangle$ again? In qiskit's textbook ([Grover's algorithm - Chapter 2. Example](https://github.com/Qiskit/textbook/blob/main/notebooks/ch-algorithms/grover.ipynb)) it is stated that "since this is a reflection about the state $|s\rangle$, where $s$ is our superposition state, we want to add a negative phase to every state orthogonal to $|s\rangle$". Why exactly are we interested to add the phase to the orthogonal states?, i.e. flip all the states except $|00\rangle$?

I've already searched a lot and while this question may seem that it was already asked before, I would like someone to give an explanation from both an intuition point of view and a mathematical one.

Comment: The best intuition for Grover's search I've seen is at https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/main/tutorials/ExploringGroversAlgorithm/VisualizingGroversAlgorithm.ipynb - it helps you view each iteration as a pair of reflections. After this, it's a matter of convincing yourself that the diffusion operator is a reflection about the mean, and Hadamards are the part that converts |00> to "the mean" (equal superposition of all states in the search space) and vice versa, and that 2|00><00| - I is reflection about |00>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grover's algorithm, and in general in amplitude amplification, diffusion is a reflection about the initial state $|\psi_0\rangle$. Which means that we can write the diffusion operator as
$$D=2| \psi_0 \rangle \langle \psi_0 | - I$$

In Grover's algorithm we start with a uniform superposition of all basis states
$$| \psi_0 \rangle = H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle$$
So,
$$D=2H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle \langle 0 |H^{\otimes n} - I$$
But, $H$ is its inverse. That means,
$$I=H^{\otimes n}H^{\otimes n}$$
And hence,
$$D=H^{\otimes n}(2|0\rangle \langle 0 | - I)H^{\otimes n}$$

So, it is a reflection about $|0\rangle$ state sandwiched by two layers of Hadamard gates.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!

Comment: I was reading again the mathematical steps and I have one question. When we do $H^{\otimes n}H^{\otimes n}$ we get $nI_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$ and $n$ is a multiplicative factor that we get from the multiplication of the two Hadamards. So, why isn't that $n$ taken in consideration in the steps before factoring on the left side and right side the Hadamard gates?

Comment: In quantum computing, we define Hadamard gate to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&1\\ 1&-1 \end{array}} \right)$ .See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Hadamard_gate) for example.

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot about the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thank you!